How to get extra functional limbs as an Arcanist?
Context: Level 14, Mythic 3 Arcanist, LN, specced into illusions more than anything else, specifically Shadow spells. Lorewise soon-to-be god of shadow, my group literally builds new pantheon in the dying world.
Current need: more arms to carry 1 Metamagic Rod and 1 Shield on top of current Staff and empty hand for casting.
Resources available:

All arcane spells up to level 8, regardless of class (via Wish if not anything else),
All divine spells up to level 9 (via Planar Bound Solar), unless Evil then up to level 7 (via Wish if not anything else),
All witch spells up to level 6 (via Witch Cohort),
Planar Binding,
Full RAW crafting.

Preferable solutions: permanent, long-term buffs or short-term buffs but easily spammable.
DISCLAIMERS:

RAW game,
Changing race is not an option, unless it's a buff that temporarily grants racial trait from race builder,
Wishes only work to the extent of replicating other spells.


You could craft Arms of the Marilith, requrires Craft Wondrous Item, animate objects and cost 15,000 gp to craft. They are not fully functional as extra arms, but in exchange, you get 4 of them, they are a permanent fixture and

each arm’s hand can hold any item the wearer could hold in one hand, allowing the wearer to have up to six total pieces of equipment ready for use at once. Once per round as a free action, the wearer can switch which items are held by which hands.

so you could rotate in the rod, for example if you want to use metamagic.

Once per round switch limit makes it just a tiny bit better item harness. Doesn't fit the requirement of being able to use staff, shield, free arm for casting and rod.
